# issue in extracting apache-tomcat-8.5.5.tar.gz file when installing tomcat8 in ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, tar, tomcat8

I have tried to install tomcat8 on ubuntu(16.04) virtual server by entering following command ( as in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
cd /tmp
curl -O http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.5/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.5.tar.gz
```

The last command gives error as below.

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar:Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have also tried to rename the tar.gz file to .tar file and extract it.but it did not work. how can i overcome this error?

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because there are no files on the server apache.mirrors.ionfish.org. 
Type in a browser the address http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.5/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.5.tar.gz and you will see information about the error:

The requested URL /tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.5/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.5.tar.gz was not found on this server.

You must open the address http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/ and check the existing versions. I see the following information:

[DIR] v8.0.50/                13-Feb-2018 06:24    -
[DIR] v8.5.28/                11-Feb-2018 20:12    -

Another way is to check the format file with the command:

file apache-tomcat-8.5.5.tar.gz

It should show information about the type of file.
For a valid file it shows "gzip compressed data".
In our case it shows "HTML document, ASCII text".

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
sudo apt-get install unzip
cd /opt
curl -O http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.15/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.15.zip
sudo unzip apache-tomcat-8.5.15.zip
sudo mv apache-tomcat-8.5.15 tomcat
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Apache Tomcat® Downloads page](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi) and download the latest core binary distribution file (ex: apache-tomcat-9.0.13.zip).

Copy the extracted content of the ZIP file to `/opt/tomcat` and follow the [installation steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804).